# Add weather WebPart using Add-PnPClientSideWebPart is not setting location

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to add a weather WebPart on a modern page in SharePoint Online.

This is the PowerShell I'm executing:

```
$jsonProperties = '
{
    "serverProcessedContent": {
        "searchablePlainTexts": {
            "webPartTitle": "Weather"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "temperatureUnit": "C",
        "locations": [
            {
                "countryName": "Australia",
                "name": "Manjimup, Australia",
                "latitude": -34.24055862426758,
                "longitude": 116.14610290527344,
                "showCustomizedDisplayName": false
            },
            {
                "countryName": "Australia",
                "name": "Bega, Australia",
                "latitude": -36.673919677734378,
                "longitude": 149.84178161621095,
                "showCustomizedDisplayName": false
            }
        ]
    }
}'

Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page https://mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/Sites/MyPage -DefaultWebPartType Weather -WebPartProperties $jsonProperties
```

The WebPart is being added but there are no weather locations, as shown below.

[image: Weather WebPart]

What am I missing for the locations to be added to the WebPart?

Comment: just guessing: maybe defining the `$jsonProperties` using a here-string fixes it? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/maximizing-the-power-of-here-string-in-powershell-for-configuration-data/

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz Either way produces an idential object with `ConvertFrom-Json`, so probably not unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the property `"dataVersion": "1.2"`. The full JSON looks like this:

```
$jsonProperties = '
{
    "dataVersion": "1.2",
    "serverProcessedContent": {
        "searchablePlainTexts": {
            "webPartTitle": "Weather"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "temperatureUnit": "C",
        "locations": [
            {
                "countryName": "Australia",
                "name": "Manjimup, Australia",
                "latitude": -34.24055862426758,
                "longitude": 116.14610290527344,
                "showCustomizedDisplayName": false
            },
            {
                "countryName": "Australia",
                "name": "Bega, Australia",
                "latitude": -36.673919677734378,
                "longitude": 149.84178161621095,
                "showCustomizedDisplayName": false
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```